# Why do so many projects prepend "v" to the git version tags?

Tags: linux, git, versioning

A lot of projects (e.g. Linux) prepend `v` to their git version tags, e.g. `v3.19` which makes parsing of those tags harder for no obvious reason. What's the sense of doing that?

Comment: Make the meaning of the number more obvious.

Comment: A possible explaination http://stackoverflow.com/a/2011372/4126482
Hope that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard naming convention for git tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006265/is-there-a-standard-naming-convention-for-git-tags)

Comment: @JonSurrell My question is specificly outlining the disadvantage (more "complicated" parsing) of prepending `v` and only asking about reasons for prepending it? The referenced question asks about a convention in general.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Is there a standard naming convention for git tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273142/6309)":

> The reason for the preceding 'v' is historical.
>   Older SCCS (cvs,rcs) could not distinguish between a tag identifier and a revision number.
>   Tag identifiers were restricted to not begin with a numeric value so that revision numbers could be detected.

That convention is not enforced with **[Semantic Versionning](http://semver.org/)** in its 2.0 revision. It was in its 1.0 revision:

> When tagging releases in a version control system, the tag for a version MUST be "`vX.Y.Z`" e.g. "`v3.1.0`".

The fact it is no longer enforced shows how optional that 'v' can be.