# How to delete a branch that ends in a period

Tags: git

Somehow one of my coworkers was able to create a branch ending with a period.  I'm not sure how he did it.  It's now causing issues when working with his remote.

The bad branch is: 'bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message.'

When I do a `git fetch taylor` it just hangs.

When I list the branches the period is invisible

```
git branch -r | grep 924
taylor/bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message
```

If I try to delete the branch without the period, I get a 404 (makes sense)

```
git push origin :taylor/bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message
error: unable to delete 'taylor/bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message': remote ref does not exist
```

If I try to delete the true branch name I get a 'invalid branch name'

```
git push origin :taylor/bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message.
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :taylor/bugfix_ESP-924-invalid-email-error-message.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having this issue to!

Comment: I'm surprised that git has problems with branch names ending with `'.'` -- but apparently it does. I wonder why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3651860/827263

Comment: Looks like you (or he) will have to fix this directly on his side: obviously the fetch stripped the trailing period and push won't let you specify it.

Comment: where is the branch? how about: - creating a new bare repository. - fetch all remotes except the one with the illegal branch name. -replace the repositories manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch is just a link to a commit. It's stored in `.git/refs/heads/branchname`. If you can access remote directly, just delete the file. But please make a backup before. Two backups are even better :)

Comment: I can delete it locally but how do I push that to the upstream server?

Comment: I meant connecting to the `taylor` by SSH.