# JGit support to escape branch names

Tags: jgit

When using [jgit](/questions/tagged/jgit) to set a branch name with illegal characters (outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651867/58530)) like so:

```java
git.checkout().setName("......my:bad:branch:name")
```

it generates a low-level git error.

Ideally I could avoid encoding those invalid characters in my code directly. Does JGit have any functionality to escape/replace/strip invalid characters?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I ended up filing a feature request with jgit, [#497123](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497123), that referenced your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2017-01-27**: Since [this commit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/b667c182cbaf56fd4382362f042062343bac0856) there is a static method `Repository::normalizeBranchName()` that escapes a given string to form a valid ref name and returns it. The changes will be release with JGit v4.7.

For earlier versions of JGit, the name must be escaped manually.

With `Repository::isValidRefName()` you can determine if the given string is a valid Git ref name. The [documentation for git check-ref-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) describes in detail the rules that a valid ref name must comply to.

I am using this method in a project that replaces all suspicious characters with an underscore (probably with some inaccuracies):

```java
String DOT_LOCK = ".lock";
String REPLACEMENT = "_";

String escapeRefName( String refName ) {
  String result = refName;
  if( result.endsWith( DOT_LOCK ) ) {
    result = result.substring( 0, result.length() - DOT_LOCK.length() );
  }
  result = result.replace( " ", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "\\", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "/", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "^", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "@", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "{", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "}", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "~", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "*", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "?", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( ":", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "[", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( ".", REPLACEMENT );
  result = result.replace( "\u007F", REPLACEMENT );
  return result;
}
```