# Why cannot the `~` tilde sign be part of a valid Git branch name?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm trying to denote Git branches from contributing users with the `~` tilde sign similar to the notation used to refer to home folders on UNIX-like operating systems but Git prevents me from doing so in that it aborts branch creation with the error message `fatal: '~' is not a valid branch name.` The branch names from contributors should look like `~alice/feature/foo`, `~bob/bugfix/bar` etc.

None of the following commands work with Git version 2.14.1:

```
$ git checkout -b '~'
fatal: '~' is not a valid branch name.
$ git checkout -b '~bar'
fatal: '~bar' is not a valid branch name.
$ git checkout -b 'foo~'
fatal: 'foo~' is not a valid branch name.
$ git checkout -b 'foo~bar'
fatal: 'foo~bar' is not a valid branch name.
```

For the moment as an alternate denotation I have decided on the `@` *at* sign as the common prefix for my purposes. But I'm rethinking the decision of making rather unusual characters part of my branch names other than the `-` hyphen and `_` underscore signs as word delimiters due to possible restrictions that may be imposed by Git itself or the underlying filesystem a Git repository happens to be e.g. checked out and thus stored on.

Comment: Duplicate question link needs to be reviewed once more. The branch name in git is actually a folder. ~ means home directory in unix systems. So, that folder already exists, hence git is unable to make such a branch. This Q&A have some detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name/2527452#2527452

Comment: @Eyorther `~` is a perfectly suitable directory name in linux. `mkdir \~` works like a charm.

Comment: @CodeCaster I voted to reopen this question since: 1/ I put some effort in answering to it with information not present on the proposed duplicate and 2/ this is not a perfect duplicate: OP asks why it is forbidden, not if it is forbidden.

Comment: @YSC mkdir ~ and mkdir /~, there is a difference. The later one makes a directory ~ in root folder.

Comment: @Eyorther The tilde name of your home directory is a shorthand managed by your shell, not by the system nor the kernel. `mkdir \~` will make the shell ignore the tilde and pass as first argument to `mkdir` the name `~` _as is_. `mkdir` is perfectly capable of creating a directory named `~`. It means nothing to him (it?).

Comment: I reopened this as requested, but want to put the link back in (StackOverflow auto-removed it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651860/which-characters-are-illegal-within-a-branch-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The rules for reference names are given in the `git check-ref-format` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html).  The tilde `~`, carat `^`, and colon `:` characters are forbidden since they are syntactic items when parsing references: `master~3` means count back three first parents from the commit to which `master` points, for instance, and `HEAD:path/to/blob` is a *file* (blob) within the current commit.

Comment: But then again if Git were very strict about special characters in branch names why doesn't it forbid the `@` *at* sign since `@` is short for the symbolic reference `HEAD`?

Comment: In fact `@`-as-a-whole *is* forbidden (rule 9) and `@{` is also forbidden (rule 8). The rules *could* be relaxed to forbid only `~` followed by digits (or end of string), since `this~that` has no defined meaning, only `this~<optional-number>`. However, Git seems to be going in the other direction (adding more restrictions) at the moment, probably because of Windows.

Answer (score 5):

A git reference (tag or branch) is forbidden to contain a tilde (`~`) since this character is used to refer to a parent commit:

- `ref~`  is a shorthand for `ref~1` and means `ref`'s first parent;
- `ref~2` means `ref`'s second parent;
- ...

Check out Paul Boxley's [Git caret and tilde](http://www.paulboxley.com/blog/2011/06/git-caret-and-tilde) article for a quick summary of the role of the tilde and caret (`^`) in git syntax.

Finally, you'll find all the documentation about git syntax for refering to commit in the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html).

Comment: I think the OP doesn't like the answer (even though it's correct). It may not be a *great* reason as I note in comment on my answer, but it *is* the (original) reason.