# git branch naming on Windows

Tags: git, git-for-windows

When I execute the command `git checkout -b /dev/myfeature` in Windows, git bash returns with this error:
`fatal: 'C:/Program Files/Git/dev/myfeature' is not a valid branch name.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

> The name of the branch to create or delete. The new
>   branch name must pass all checks defined by git-check-ref-format[1].
>   Some of these checks may restrict the characters allowed in a branch
>   name.

And from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format:

> They cannot begin or end with a slash / or contain multiple
>   consecutive slashes (see the --normalize option below for an exception
>   to this rule)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure here, but I suspect the leading "/" 
This is similar to this question 
[Which characters are illegal within a branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651860/which-characters-are-illegal-within-a-branch-name)

Which has a trailing "/" in the list... so I'm suspicious of the leading slash