# How to escape whitespace in Gerrit push topic?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%topic='test topic'
```

This fails with error `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in HEAD:refs/for/master%topic=test topic`

I tried `%topic='\"test\ topic\"'`, `%topic='test\ topic'` but it didn't work, problem is the whitespace, it supports `%topic='test_topic'`

How do I escape the whitespace?

Comment: You cannot use spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651860/which-characters-are-illegal-within-a-branch-name

Comment: Maybe you mean "Gerrit topic"? There is no such thing in Git itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master -o topic='test topic'
```

See https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.0.4/intro-user.html#topics

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "topic" in Git. You are just using some conventions to embed metadata about the branch in its name. See `man git-check-ref-format` for information about what characters are permitted in a branch name. Most relevant is rule 4:

> 4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values
>             are lower than \040, or \177 DEL), **space**, tilde ~, caret ^, or
>             colon : anywhere.

Comment: The question is about Gerrit tool. I just fixed the title.

Comment: I don't think that changes the answer. The refspec still has to follow the rules established by Git; it's just Gerrit that sets the convention.