# Why do some Git branch names have slashes in them?

Tags: git

I'm reading this tutorial
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch

It contains an example where it adds a remote repo

`git remote add coworkers_repo git@bitbucket.org:coworker/coworkers_repo.git`

and then fetches a branch

```
git fetch coworkers_repo coworkers/feature_branch
fetching coworkers/feature_branch
```

In this last command, why the name of the branch name is "coworkers/feature_branch" has a forward slash? Shouldn't the branch be a string of characters such as "coworkers" or "feature_branch"? Or is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

Slashes are allowed ([along with other special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651860/which-characters-are-illegal-within-a-branch-name)), and some Git UI software (such as SourceTree) will use them to group branches as if in folders. This results in something like so:

```
coworkers
  feature_branch1
  feature_branch2
customers
  feature_branch1
  feature_branch2
```

As [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) points out, "both one/two and one/two/three are valid branch names, but you can't have both in the same repo. Due to the way branches are represented in the .git directory tree, that would require one/two to be both a regular file and a directory."

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of characters that are allowed in a branch (or other ref) name, including the slash.  In fact, a branch `foo` is really just a reference of the form `refs/heads/foo`.  As such, adding more slashes is totally possible.

The reason people often use them is to roughly categorize their branches.  For example, at work we share a single repository for our projects instead of using forks, so some developers prefer to create branches named `username/branch` to avoid conflicting with other users' branches.  In addition, some projects prefer to categorize refs into groups like `feature/*`, `bugfix/*`, or `hotfix/*`.

The [documentation for `git check-ref-format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) outlines the valid formats.  Because references are stored in the file system, there are some practical limitations to what can be in a ref.  For example, you cannot have both branches `foo` (ref `refs/heads/foo`) and `foo/bar` (ref `refs/heads/foo/bar`) because in the former case `foo` would need to be a file and in the latter case it would need to be a directory.  Also, if your file system is case insensitive or restricts certain byte sequences, that will often be reflected in whether you can store branches differing in case or using the byte sequences on your system.

There is a plan for a ref backend called reftable that doesn't suffer from these limitations, but it has not yet been implemented in Git.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is (a) legal and (b) a *convention*. How a team decides to name branches is up to the team. But there are a variety of popular and widely used conventions where slashes are used to categorize what the branch is about. See for example:

https://codingsight.com/git-branching-naming-convention-best-practices/

and especially

[What are some examples of commonly used practices for naming git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273695/what-are-some-examples-of-commonly-used-practices-for-naming-git-branches)

I would argue that your question is actually a duplicate of that, even though it was posed from a different angle.

I should add: the slash-based approach is *so* popular that many automated tools are based around it.