# How can I create folder in remote origin in git

Tags: git

I am new in development, and so far seen branches being added to remote origin. But recently came across the case where subfolders can be found in Remote origin. Like this doesn't mean I wish to push a folder to git.
But it certainly looks like origin/some_feature/branch_name where some_feature is a folder inside which branch is there.
Can anyone help me by achieving the same.
Is it simply like git push origin/some_feature branch_name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68009994/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+slash+branch+name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't folders. They are just branch names with slashes in them. `origin` is the name of the remote and `some_feature/branch_name` is the name of a branch. Create the branch, give it a commit, and push it, just like any other branch.

Comment: The command would be: create branch `git switch -c some_feature/branch_name`, push branch `git push -u origin some_feature/branch_name`