# Skip copying some branches/tags to local Git with `git fetch --all`

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I have many remotes added to my Git. Each remote is a repository for one developer. Every day I `fetch --all` to see any new branches they create that are ready to review.

However, developers can push "private" branches to the remote. Say, all branches named with an underscore prefix are not ready to review, while other branches are ready to review.

When doing the `git fetch --all`, my Git graph (by `/libexec/git-core/git-gui`) will see all branches, no matter whether they have the underscore prefix or not. It complicates the graph.

I want `git fetch` to ignore those `_XXXX` branches from being downloaded to my local Git. So when I view the Git graph it's like:

- **Shows branches:**   `RemoteA/Branch1` , `RemoteB/Branch1`, `RemoteB/Branch2`
- **Ignores branches:**  `RemoteA/_Branch2`, `RemoteB/_Branch3`

How can I do this?

Comment: For more on **negative refspec** introduced with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), see "[Git - What is “Refspec”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287272/6309)".

Comment: Actually `git fetch --all` means fetching from all remotes if you have more than one, not all remote branches/tags. The latter is actually controlled by the fetch spec(s), so in `+refs/heads/*`, the `*` means to fetch all heads from that remote.

So you can either explicitly specify the ones you want, or use a negative fetch spec with Git 2.29+

Answer (score 20):

### Update for Git v2.29.0

With [negative refspecs](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0192df6306d4d9ad77f6015a053925b13155834),<sup>1</sup> added in Git v2.29, you can achieve your original intent without any changes to your coworkers’ habits.

For each coworker’s remote, add a negative refspec (i.e. prefixed with `^`) to exclude the `_`-prefixed branches. This is loosely adapted from [the unit test for `.git/config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0192df6306d4d9ad77f6015a053925b13155834#diff-023e7d3eb6ce02f7b78cf14a087132e8d7475ff264854b63085fa5a1bbdc6314R16-R36) and [the one for negative patterns](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0192df6306d4d9ad77f6015a053925b13155834#diff-023e7d3eb6ce02f7b78cf14a087132e8d7475ff264854b63085fa5a1bbdc6314R76-R87). See the last line in the code block below for "Fred’s" remote.

```ini
[remote "fred"]
    url = something.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/fred/*
    fetch = ^refs/heads/_*
```

You have two options to set this for `fred` on the command line:

- `git config --add remote.fred.fetch '^refs/heads/_*'`
- `git remote set-branches --add fred '^refs/heads/_*'`

### Original answer

Expanding on [VonC's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26624110/241211) with a special "review" folder,<sup>2</sup> you can modify your `.git/config`’s entries for your coworkers’ remotes. Here is [the relevant documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Where it was once

```ini
[remote "fred"]
    url = something.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/fred/*
```

You can change it to

```ini
[remote "fred"]
    url = something.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/review/*:refs/remotes/fred/review/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/other_pattern/*:refs/remotes/fred/other_pattern/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/specific_branch:refs/remotes/fred/specific_branch
```

After doing so, you may have to clean up the references to refs you have already fetched, but future `git fetch --all`s or `git fetch fred`s will not update anything outside of the patterns you specified.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The documentation on negative refspecs is kind of minimal and buried in [a longer passage](https://git-scm.com/docs/pull-fetch-param/2.29.0#Documentation/pull-fetch-param.txt-ltrefspecgt), so the best place to look is [in Git's history](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0192df6306d4d9ad77f6015a053925b13155834) or in [VonC's answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287272/241211), where he pulls the relevant parts together.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Or as many special or interesting folders and branches as you need.</sub>

Comment: Great answer. Let's add how do to it with tags. Basically `^refs/tags/pattern` along with `git config remote.origin.tagopt --tags` should do the trick

Comment: @CervEd Go for it. Please link relevant documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I needed this to stop tracking the `gh-pages` branch on a github repo (which contains a history of the CI builds that I don't need on my machine).  The negative refspec for this was: `fetch = ^refs/heads/gh-pages`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a '`_`' naming convention, you could use namespaces, pushing the branch in `origin/review/Branch1` (`git push Branch1:review/Branch1`)
(named "group" [in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065944/6309), or "hierarchical branch name (branch names with slash) in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309))

That way, you only have to fetch what is in the "review' namespace:

```
git fetch +refs/heads/review/*:refs/remotes/origin/review/*
```

---

The only other option would be a script, which would:

- list the remote branches (without fetching anything): [`git ls-remote origin`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)
- for each branch with the right name, [fetch only that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369199/6309)

Comment: but how to do to for all remote? git fetch +refs/heads/review/*:refs/remotes/origin/review/* means I have to type in RemoteA in the command to replace the 'origin'.  Anything similar but work for --all?

Comment: @palazzotrain you need to loop over all your remote (listed by `git remote`): easily scriptable.

Comment: @Michael I have documented those negative refspec in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287272/6309).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one step with an alias. Add this to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```ini
[alias]
    fall = !sh -c 'git fetch --all && git branch -r | sed /HEAD/d | grep /_ | xargs git branch -dr' --
```

And then just say `git fall`. It will delete all remote branches that contain `/_`.

You can observe the intricacies of aliases that are shell commands.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `ignore-refs` option:

```
git fetch --ignore-refs branch123
```

Comment: I am using git 2.8.4, released after this post, but I don't have the `ignore-refs` option. I did some Googling, and the only references I have to it [are for `git svn`.](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-git-svn-Allow-certain-refs-to-be-ignored-td6867817.html)