# git config: remote.<name>.fetch - is it possible to set up exceptions?

Tags: git

It is possible to set up rules like `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` to fetch all branches matching certain glob.

But is it possible to exclude something from the list? For example, I don't want to fetch anything from `refs/heads/X/*` because it is used by our automated tool, and there're often lots of small branches I have no need to see ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Git v2.29.0, there is a way. [Negative refspecs](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e3ec76a20d6abf5dd8ceb3f5f2c157000e4c13e) have been added to the logic.

Add another line to your *.git/config* for that remote that looks like this: `fetch = ^refs/heads/X/*`. You can [find more details in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37165609/241211).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  To exclude `X/*` you must list (positively) everything *not* `X/*`.

Depending on how you name your refs / branches, this may be easy enough, or may be especially difficult.  You could automate it to a large extent using `git ls-remote` and a script (use grep, or python code, or whatever, to exclude `X/*` while adding every other reference).