# Rules when naming Git branches

Tags: git

When I name branches in Git, I always tend to start with a letter. `mybranch89` for example.

Are there any rules to naming Git branches? For example, should I always begin with a letter, or are number only branch names possible such as `876`

Comment: They can certainly start with numbers - many projects use branches to do big fixes on old versions.

Comment: Strange that this was marked a duplicate. Rules != best practices.

Comment: @Thomas those were my thoughts too. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rules are [rather complicated](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format), but when you consider that branches end up as files on the filesystem, they make sense:

> Git imposes the following rules on how references are named:
>
> 1. They can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but
>      no slash-separated component can begin with a dot . or end with the
>      sequence .lock.
> 2. They must contain at least one /. This enforces the presence of a
>      category like heads/, tags/ etc. but the actual names are not
>      restricted. If the --allow-onelevel option is used, this rule is
>      waived.
> 3. They cannot have two consecutive dots .. anywhere.
> 4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values
>      are lower than \040, or \177 DEL), space, tilde ~, caret ^, or colon
>      : anywhere.
> 5. They cannot have question-mark ?, asterisk *, or open bracket [
>      anywhere. See the --refspec-pattern option below for an exception to
>      this rule.
> 6. They cannot begin or end with a slash / or contain multiple
>      consecutive slashes (see the --normalize option below for an
>      exception to this rule)
> 7. They cannot end with a dot ..
> 8. They cannot contain a sequence @{.
> 9. They cannot be the single character @.
> 10. They cannot contain a \.

Note that this is for naming of *references*, not branches. A branch is a reference that looks like `refs/heads/<branchname>`.