# Using git branch names with / in TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server with git source control repository.  I would like to be able to name branches with the / character separating words like, "dev/feat/button".  Git supports this however the TFS build system runs into a problem with the /'s being in the name.  It properly creates the directories but runs into a problem cleaning the directory because it thinks the entire "dev/feat/button" is a file and not a nested set of directories.  Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated by git-tfs, you cannot use a '/' in a TFS branch name, since [TFS has this notion of branch path](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files):

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E  $/Repository/ProjectTrunk
           \                              
            M <- N     $/Repository/ProjectBranch
```

That is very different from Git, for which a branch is just a set of commits in a graph.

Comment: that link your provided is for tfs source control not git.  That does not apply to the git source control within tfs.  I can create a branch name in git with a / in it.  The only thing that fails is the build scripts when trying to clean the workspace. It thinks that the / is part of the file name and not a directory.

Comment: @Brandt I agree: my point was to reference TFS, and yes, Git does support '/' (as a naming convention for branch namespace: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065944/6309).

Answer (score 1):

I've tested in TFS 2015.3 by creating a branch with name `dev/test`:

[image]

Then in TFS build, select this branch:

[image]

TFS build can get this branch without issue:

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1. Which version of Git are you using with that TFS 2015.3?

Comment: It's git version 2.11.0.windows.1.