# Multiple git repos for flask backend

Tags: python, git, flask

I have a project that is made in flask (python). I want to be able to easily separate the frontend from the backend, into multiple git repos. I've tried making 2 repos in the same folder, but that's a pain to do and needs a lot of configuration. My current directory has

- static
- storage
- templates
- other files such as `app.py` and `.env`

I want to sort them like this:

| Frontend Repo | Backend Repo |
| --- | --- |
| static | storage |
| templates | other files |

I would be fine with changing some configuration inside the flask app that changed where it looks for the template/static folders, but I'm stuck on how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have one repository with 3 or 4 branches. `master`, `develop` (optional), `develop_backend` and `develop_frontend`.

Starting from an empty repository you could now commit backend files to the backed branch and frontend files to the frontend one. Then merge them to either `master` or the joined `develop` branch whenever it makes sense.

For a visualization see the vizualization of the general merging approch see the image from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273695/what-are-some-examples-of-commonly-used-practices-for-naming-git-branches).

[image]

**[update]**

You say you want your devs to have only access to frontend or backend. What you could do is creating dedicated downstream repositories which **clone only the frontend branch**.

Details see on how to clone only single branches see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: I don't want my frontend devs to have access to my backend code.

Comment: I'll look into that.